# How to generate XML & XSD for DB table

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-database, datasource, xml-generation

I need to create some reports. I am using Crystal Reports and I need to use XML & XSD files as a data source for my report structure. 
Somehow I have managed to generate XSD file. However I cannot convert it to the XML due to some errors I have in it. 
Googling around I only ran into situations where people write custom code for generating those files and in most cases those files contains data too.

Is there a way to **generate valid XML & XSD files for specific DB or DB table with button click** in some studio/workbench and if not why is that?

From my point of view those files should only describe table structure, something like CREATE TABLE script.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a typed dataset with visual studio. The generated xsd file will contain the structure of the selected tables.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983556(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: will I have both xml & xsd file or only one of those?

Comment: If you create a dataset you'll get the xsd schema. But it's "trivial" to get XML directly from database using T-SQL. http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms178107.aspx